# How to write a file in Python

Tags: python

I am making a French Translator and I want to make a 'Save' button that will save what is currently entered into the entry fields.

```
e1 = Entry(master)
e2 = Entry(master)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

def write():
        name = 'SavedFile.txt'
        hello = int(3)
        file = open(name,'w+') 
        file.write(e1.get()) 

        file.close()

menubar = Menu(master)
master.config(menu=menubar)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Save", command=write())
```

Changing file.write(e1.get()) to file.write('hello'), works and writes 'Hello' to SavedFile.

But I want it so when I click 'Save' under 'File', it rewrites to the file (preferably without overwriting what is there)

P.s.,

```
s = e1.get()
```

will actually make s = to whatever is currently in the field

Comment: Write to the file, but re-write to the file by clicking a button

Comment: Perhaps you want to open the file using `'a'` (append mode) instead of `'w+'`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your `Entry` class is, but I suspect this will work:

```
with open(name, 'a') as f:
    f.write(str(e.get()))
```

The `str` might or might not be necessary.

Comment: Ah I fixed it, I had write() instead of write